# NA variables in dplyr summary r

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline, frequency, cut

I am trying to create a table, which includes relative frequencies (`counts`) of variables taken from two groups (`A` and `B`) that fall within pre-given temporal `intervals`. My problem is that if a row starts with 0 seconds (see `start_sec`), the variable does not fall within the 0-5 seconds `interval` but is marked as `NA` (see Output). My wish is to include these cases within the above-mentioned interval.

This is a dummy example:

#### Variables

```
group <-   c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
person <-  c("p1","p1","p1","p3","p2","p2","p1","p1","p2")
start_sec <- c(0,10.7,11.8,3.9,7.4,12.1,0,3.3,0)
dur_sec <- c(7.1,8.2,9.3,10.4,11.5,12.6,13.7,14.8,15.9)
```

#### Data frame

```
df <-  data.frame(group,person,start_sec,dur_sec)
df
```

[image: Data frame]

#### Pipeline

```
df %>%
group_by(group,person, interval=cut(start_sec, breaks=c(0,5,10,15))) %>%
summarise(counts= n(),sum_dur_sec=sum(dur_sec))
```

#### Output (so far)

[image: Output]

Thank you in advance for all comments and feedback!

Comment: For including 0 in the 0-5 interval, you may want to try adding `include.lowest = TRUE` to your `cut()` function. I'm afraid I'm not entirely clear what your desired outputs for `counts_change_perc` and `dur_s_change_perc` are.

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked! I realized that the question about the additional columns is smth I could do manually, so I removed it from the post.

Comment: I was wondering, is there an option of adding a new column (`interval_end`) next to the `interval` column that contains the last number of the interval. For example: (0,30] and in the `interval_end` is 30, for (30,60] it would be 60 etc.?